# URL Redirect not working In HTML link

Tags: php, html, url, redirect, hyperlink

my domain is www.xyz.com in this i have a page like www.xyz.com/test.php when u

open this page it'll show u a link like click here , the address of link is like

www.abc.net/secret/vEX0szqBscdQx but when i click this click here it shows 404 error

page not found and there url look like this

http://www.xyz.com/"https://www.abc.net/secret/vEX0szqBscdQx/"

its not redirection the page please help me.

ok lets get real

this is my code

Comment: we cant help u with no code

Comment: my chrome says `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: You might have a broken HTML, Please check source from "view source code" of browser...

Answer (score 1):

When you reference external `URI` you need to specify the full `URI` including the protocol, e.g. `http`, `https` etc:

Try:

```
<a href="https://www.abc.net/secret/vEX0szqBscdQx">click here</a>
```

Or the shorthand to keep the same scheme/protocol(`http`/`https`):

```
<a href="//www.abc.net/secret/vEX0szqBscdQx">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Http 404 error is a clear indication that your url is wrong or does not exist. Specify the full url in your code.